# Laravel blade img not loading from different links

Tags: php, html, image, laravel, url

Situation:
I have page-template.blade.php file with image:

```
<img src="./images/picture.png">
```

And i have three views which extends page-template:

- landing-page.blade.php   http://exaple.com/
- login.blade.php          http://exaple.com/login
- change-pass.blade.php    http://exaple.com/change-password/token

When i go to site from http://exaple.com/ and http://exaple.com/login i see picture.png (browser read it from http://exaple.com/images/picture.png ). But when I go to site from http://exaple.com/change-password/token then I don't see picutre (because browser star read it from: http://exaple.com/change-password/images/picture.png which doesn't exist)

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) helper to avoid this kind of problem:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/picture.png') }}">
```

The image should be in `public/images`

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of Blade templates.
When you start path from dot `src="./images/picture.png"`, web-browser is trying to find PNG file relatively to directory of current HTML file in URL.

If you have an image `<img src="./images/picture.png">`
in file available by URL: `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file`,
browser will try to fetch file from `http://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/images/picture.png`

As @alexey-mezenin said, you can use `asset()` helper or use absolute path
`<img src="/images/picture.png">` if you sure, that your site will never be available in subdirectory.

Comment: thanks for explanation - in my case I change `http://exaple.com/change-password/token` to `http://exaple.com/change-password?token=xxx` and it works :)